# How do I link a VS2008 C++ project as a DLL instead of a LIB?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll

I have the C++ source code in a Visual Studio project from another developer that compiles into a static lib.  I need to change it so that it builds a dll from that code so that I can call it from C#.  I went into the project properties in Visual Studio and changed the configuration type to a DLL.  However, it now gives lots of linker errors like:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __CAP_Enter_Function  XXXFilter.obj XXXFramework
```

What else do I need to do in Visual Studio and in the code to produce a dll from the code instead of a lib?  The library is huge so writing a wrapper is not an option.  I have the code so I should be able to make it build a dll.

I am not a very experienced C++ dev but I am in C# and visual studio.  The C++ command line is:

/Od /Oi /D "_DEBUG" /D "_XBOX" /D "XBOX" /D "_XBOX_CRT_DEPRECATE_INSECURE" /D "_MBCS" /FD /MTd /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fp"Debug/AtgFramework.pch" /Fo"Debug\" /Fd"Debug\vc80.pdb" /W4 /nologo /c /Zi /TP

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the C++ project someone has used the [/callcap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254291%28VS.80%29.aspx) Visual C++ argument.  I don't think there is a C++ setting for it so it's most likely in the "Additional options" / "Command Line" section.  Remove the option and it should link ok.

Comment: Thanks.  That solves a lot of the linking errors but not all of them.  There are many more unresolved external symbol errors.  I'd post them but there are 1700 of them.  The C++ command line is:

/Od /Oi /D "_DEBUG" /D "_XBOX" /D "XBOX" /D "_XBOX_CRT_DEPRECATE_INSECURE" /D "_MBCS" /FD /MTd /Yu"stdafx.h" /Fp"Debug/AtgFramework.pch" /Fo"Debug\\" /Fd"Debug\vc80.pdb" /W4 /nologo /c /Zi /TP

Comment: I can't comment on the other unresolved external's.  Most likely they are required libraries used by the source and the compiler switches will not help.